# AMP Cache and Dynamic Rendering

Tags: caching, amp-html

I have a question regarding the AMP Cache and dynamic rendering. Let me explain the situation.

I am developing an app that may generate valid AMP websites dynamically from an API (i.e. www.foo.com/amp/123). The other option is to actually store it somewhere in a disk as a static `HTML` file.

Now I wonder if AMP will actually Cache the dynamically generated websites, which implies that storing static HTML files is not necessary and my server will receive fewer requests.

Am I understanding how this work properly?